# Fail to dynamic image in pkpass

Tags: php, base64

I'm creating a PKpass with a dynamic image in Base64 in PHP but when I add it to my generic pass, it doesn't show me the image.

Then I tried to save it in a png file and then call it but it doesn't appear in the pass either

Could you help me to see how to integrate a base64 image in a PKpass? Thank you

Comment: Code, debugging information and an example would all help to understand your problem better :)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.